# How to export/import full OracleDB data dump?

Tags: oracle

I am new to Oracledb. please help me to export whole data Dump and import same to another db to create another copy of database.

Comment: If you're new to Oracle Database, this is a lot of concepts to get a handle on. PL/SQL APIs, Directories, Schemas, parallelism, etc. We do give you a wizard that will help you with this in Oracle SQL Developer. Do you have OS level access to the servers for both databases?

Comment: no i don't have full OS level access right now,is it required?

Comment: it depends...if the 2 databases are on the same machine, you could have a directory defined in the database that is available to both instances of Oracle...and you could run your job to do the export and do the import - without ever touching the OS yourself. Big IF there though

Answer (score 2):

You need an administrative account (for example SYSTEM). Assuming you have this, the steps are:

- create a directory object inside the database to map to a physical directory on both source and target
- export the source database
- import into the target database

For example

```
SQL> create directory X as '/u01/big_directory';

expdp system/mypassword@source full=Y directory=X dumpfile=full.dmp logfile=fullexp.log

impdp system/mypassword@target full=Y directory=X dumpfile=full.dmp logfile=fullimp.log
```

Also, check the "Database Utilities" guide in the standard Oracle documentation set for your release at docs.oracle.com